# Random performance of AUPRC

Tags: machine-learning, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes

I've been trying to understand how to interpret what random performance would be for a model I have on the AUPRC score. By 'random performance' I mean the worst possible performance. Purely unintelligent, meaning the model has learned nothing.

With AUPRC for example, random performance leads to a score of 0.5. If you get AUC <= 0.5, then your model serves no use.

With AUPRC, I have learned that this base performance you want to beat is equal to the number of positive samples divided by the total number of samples (for example in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532038/comparing-auprc-scores-in-case-of-different-baselines) post). However I still don't understand *why* this is the worst case performance, and I can't find anywhere that explains this.

**A concrete example**:
Let's say I have 20 samples of Class 0 for every sample of Class 1. Then according to the above post, the worst possible performance I could get on AUPRC (where class 1 is the positive class) is 1/21 = 0.047...

**My Question**:

*Why* is 1/21 the worst performance for AUPRC in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is as follows:

If you know nothing about the data other than the fact that there are $20$ instances of category $0$ for every one instance of category $1$, the most sensible prediction about the probability of a new observation belonging to category $1$ is $1/21$.

This kind of comparison to a naïve model is routine in other forms of modeling. For instance, the usual $R^2$ in OLS linear regression can be seen is a comparison of your model performance to the performance of a model that predicts the overall mean every time. The approach here is the same: use the [prior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/583115/247274) probability as your best guess of the posterior probability, since you have no features to help you make a better prediction of the posterior probability.